# What does a minus sign mean in the Leak Instrument?

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xcode-instruments

I'm using Xcode's Instruments to find out if there's any leaks in my App. But I find the graph a little confusing. The app gets a cross when doing a certain job, but after that it gets minus signs only.

[image]

The reference count seems to get zero finally. I'm not very sure about the reading.

[image]

The [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Instruments_help_articles/FindingMemoryLeaksinYourApp/FindingMemoryLeaksinYourApp.html) is a bit outdated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no explanation in the more recent [Leaks instrument documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Instrument-Leaks.html)  about the snapshot icons.

[image]

By profiling code that leaks, here is a meaning for the leak indicators:

- Green check (tick): No leak occurred in the snapshot interval (and no prior leaks exist).
- Red x (cross): One or more leaks occurred in the snapshot interval.
- Grey dash (minus): No new leak occurred in the current snapshot interval, but a leak from a prior snapshot still remains.

If leaked object from the earlier snapshot was deallocated, you would have seen a green check instead of a grey dash.

You can [submit a documentation bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) to Apple requesting that an explanation be added to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

That's the evolution (or Delta) of the instance [Reference Counter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)(ARC is applicable to Swift and Objective-C).

+1 is when an object is referred to (aka a variable points to that object), -1 is when that variable is set to nil.

The column immediately right of this one shows you the actual ref count for that object. When it reaches 0, the object is actually marked for release.

Comment: Thanks! So I don't need to worry about the red cross?

Comment: To be specific, the minus sign I was talking about was the diamond one in pic. 1.